# How to change data source with vue?

Tags: json, vue.js, filter

With the following codes, I can list a "remote" JSON file with Vue.

Because my JSON file is too big, I wanted to send a parameter called `pageNumber` to the URL file.

I can see the `pageNumber` on the page, but it shows `data1.json?pg=[object% 20HTMLInputElement]` in the URL.

Actually I need more than that. I have to submit all the values in the form. `Data1.json, data1.asp, data1.php` files.

As a result, I need to give Vue a data source that I filtered.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="app">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
<form id="urlParameterForm">
<input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate">
<input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate">
<input type="number" name="pageNumber" id="pageNumber" value="1" v-on:input="changePage">
<input type="submit" value="Filter" id="Filter">
   <p>Page : {{ pageActive }}</p>
   </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="card" v-for="dta in dataTable">
            <img class="card-img-top" v-bind:src="(dta.bolge+'.jpg')" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{dta.bolge}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{dta.sube}}</p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">Total Amount {{dta.netTutar}} .</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="page1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

page1.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        dataTable: [],
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageActive: 0,
        url: './data1.json?pg=' + pageNumber + ''
    },
    methods: {

        changePage: function (event) {
            this.pageNumber = event.target.value;
            this.pageActive = event.target.value;
        },

        loadJSON(callback) {

            var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            xobj.open('GET', this.url, true)
            xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                    callback(xobj.responseText);
                }
            };
            xobj.send(null);
        },
        init() {
            let that = this
            that.loadJSON(function (response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                that.dataTable = data.dataTable
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.init()
    }

})
```

data1.json

```
{
  "dataTable": [
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Adana Subesi",
      "netTutar": 6.499374000000016e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Aksaray Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.234576999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Ardahan Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.887150000000001e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Batman Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.701832999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Çorum Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.663578999999996e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Erzurum Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.212622999999991e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Eskişehir Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.628607999999991e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Isparta Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.462259999999998e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Karaman Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.776750000000006e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Kırıkkale Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.855070000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Muş Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.199937999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Sakarya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.829720999999989e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Şanlıurfa Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.823557000000007e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Şırnak Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.675855999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Trabzon Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.097863999999994e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Van Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.528952999999987e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Afyonkarahisar Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.972799999999994e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Antalya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.528340000000043e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Artvin Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.710900000000002e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Aydın Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.227300999999986e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Balıkesir Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.721826999999994e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Bitlis Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.019894000000000e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Bolu Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.716130000000007e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Bursa Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.114886000000080e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Çanakkale Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.524065999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Düzce Subesi",
      "netTutar": 9.727560000000001e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Erzincan Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.497870000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Hatay Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.730510999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Iğdır Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.341670000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Kahramanmaraş Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.231586999999985e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Kars Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.581170000000006e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Kırşehir Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.357310000000006e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Mersin Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.025113000000006e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Niğde Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.041342000000000e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Sivas Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.790955999999995e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Tekirdağ Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.944850999999987e+004
    },
    {},
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Adıyaman Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.820864999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Amasya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.123514000000000e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Bartın Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.758740000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Bayburt Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.044470000000000e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Burdur Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.440650000000011e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Giresun Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.396075999999998e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Hakkari Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.755100000000006e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "İzmir Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.318144500000018e+005
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Karabük Subesi",
      "netTutar": 7.140900000000002e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Kastamonu Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.099207999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Kilis Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.663510000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Kütahya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.738236999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Malatya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.360268999999993e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Manisa Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.334794000000000e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Mardin Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.426568999999990e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Nevşehir Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.781070000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Rize Subesi",
      "netTutar": 9.731959999999997e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Samsun Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.853689999999991e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Sinop Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.248460000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Tunceli Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.586630000000000e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Yalova Subesi",
      "netTutar": 6.285410000000009e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Yozgat Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.220697999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Zonguldak Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.757073000000008e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Ağrı Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.742540999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Ankara Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.670151500000000e+005
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Bilecik Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.951650000000003e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Bingöl Subesi",
      "netTutar": 8.603440000000004e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Çankırı Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.323980000000001e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Denizli Subesi",
      "netTutar": 3.177174999999988e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Diyarbakır Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.651844000000007e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Edirne Subesi",
      "netTutar": 9.572680000000004e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Doğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Elazığ Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.726290999999997e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Gaziantep Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.729336000000015e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Gümüşhane Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.342086000000001e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "İstanbul Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.585003299999837e+005
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Kayseri Subesi",
      "netTutar": 4.351594999999998e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Kırklareli Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.109510999999999e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Marmara",
      "sube": "Kocaeli Subesi",
      "netTutar": 5.770894000000013e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "İç Anadolu",
      "sube": "Konya Subesi",
      "netTutar": 6.391753000000029e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Muğla Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.810038999999991e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Ordu Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.101259999999993e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "sube": "Osmaniye Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.826947999999996e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Güneydoğu Anadolu",
      "sube": "Siirt Subesi",
      "netTutar": 9.255639999999999e+003
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Karadeniz",
      "sube": "Tokat Subesi",
      "netTutar": 2.010617999999995e+004
    },
    {
      "bolge": "Ege",
      "sube": "Uşak Subesi",
      "netTutar": 1.051503000000000e+004
    }
  ]
}
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/omerx/fap75qjb/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `page1.js`, notice that `pageNumber` is not yet declared (but it exists in the document):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        dataTable: [],
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageActive: 0,
        url: './data1.json?pg=' + pageNumber ❌ `pageNumber` not what you think
    },
    //...
```

[DOM elements with IDs are automatically added as global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). Since you have an `<input>` element with `id="pageNumber"`, your `pageNumber` variable actually refers to that element.

And `'data1.json?pg=' + pageNumber` would invoke `HTMLInputElement.prototype.toString()`, yielding `[object HTMLInputElement]` as the suffix.

I think you are actually trying to refer to `this.pageNumber` in the `data`, but you can't do that in the same declaration. Perhaps you want a reactive `url` prop that changes with `this.pageNumber`, which can be done with a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data: {
    pageNumber: 1,
    // url: './data1.json?pg=' + pageNumber  // DON'T DO THIS
  },
  computed: {
    url() {
      return './data1.json?pg=' + this.pageNumber
    }
  }
})
```